# How to fix "calibration_pb2 from 'object_detection.protos' " error (Windows)

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, object-recognition

I've tried to run the below code but it always gives a set of errors. I tried searching the answers but none work for my code, there are two files named 'object_detection' one in the research folder and other in the object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg folder which might be causing the error but i tried to change the path but the errors still persist

I'm trying to execue this command:

```
C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python train.py -- 
logtostderr --train_dir=training/ -- 
pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

but have the following errors coming up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
1. File "train.py", line 51, in <module>
   from object_detection.builders import model_builder
2. File "C:\Users\Swayam\mypython\lib\site-packages\object_detection- 
   0.1- 
   py3.7.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 27, in 
   <module>
   from object_detection.builders import post_processing_builder
3. File "C:\Users\Swayam\mypython\lib\site-packages\object_detection- 
   0.1- 
   py3.7.egg\object_detection\builders\post_processing_builder.py", 
   line 2 
   2, in <module>
   from object_detection.protos import post_processing_pb2
4. File "C:\Users\Swayam\mypython\lib\site-packages\object_detection- 
   0.1- 
   py3.7.egg\object_detection\protos\post_processing_pb2.py", line 15, 
   in 
   <module>
   from object_detection.protos import calibration_pb2 as 
   object__detection_dot_protos_dot_calibration__pb2
5. ImportError: cannot import name 'calibration_pb2' from 
   'object_detection.protos' (C:\Users\Swayam\mypython\lib\site- 
packages\object_detection-0.1- 
py3.7.egg\object_detection\protos\__init__.py)
```

I've tried using the

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

command but it brings up errors too.

Also, the environment is not made in conda, could that be the cause of the error? Though all the necessary installations are present in the existing virtual environment.

Comment: Which version of the protobuf compiler are you using?

Comment: The Version is 3.7.1

Comment: I used version 3.0.0 and it works fine. Try using this version.

Comment: The 4th error tells you exactly what the problem lies. I use protobuf 3.0.0 and in file `post_processing_pb2.py` there is no such importing line
   `from object_detection.protos import calibration_pb2 as object__detection_dot_protos_dot_calibration__pb2`

Comment: I installed protobuf 3.0.0 still no luck

Comment: Can you pass the test script? `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`, if this one succeeds, then your installation should be fine,

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution:
Check if the file
"calibration_pb2.py"
is located in the following path, in your case may be this one:
`C:\Users\Swayam\mypython\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1- 
py3.7.egg\object_detection\protos\`

If not, just copy it from your working path:
`C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\protos\`

If it works, I sugggest you try to copy all the *pb2.py files into the path mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

you just compile this

```
protoc --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\argmax_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\bipartite_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_predictor.proto .\object_detection\protos\eval.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\grid_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\hyperparams.proto .\object_detection\protos\image_resizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\input_reader.proto .\object_detection\protos\losses.proto .\object_detection\protos\matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\mean_stddev_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\model.proto .\object_detection\protos\optimizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\pipeline.proto .\object_detection\protos\post_processing.proto .\object_detection\protos\preprocessor.proto .\object_detection\protos\region_similarity_calculator.proto .\object_detection\protos\square_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map.proto .\object_detection\protos\train.proto .\object_detection\protos\keypoint_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\multiscale_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\graph_rewriter.proto .\object_detection\protos\calibration.proto
```

it will resolve the issue